# how to initializes a collection (list) by copying the parameters from a constructor?

Tags: c++, list, class, containers

I've a class `PokemonCollection` which has a private list which accepts a pair.

Now what I've to do is, when I make an object"collection" of that class `PokemonCollection` in `main()` function, I pass some pairs to the constructor, and in the constructor I've to initialize the private list of the class.

```
PokemonCollection collection({pair<string, size_t>("Pikachu", 25), 
pair<string, size_t> ("Raticate", 20), pair<string, size_t>("Raticate", 20), 
pair<string, size_t>("Bulbasaur", 1), pair<string, size_t>("Pikachu", 25), 
pair<string, size_t>("Diglett", 50)});
```

this confuses me alot, can someone kindly help me as I'm a beginner,
also I've to print that private list too.

`collection.print();`

where print is public function of my class.

class definition:

```
class PokemonCollection{
    public: 
        void print();
    private: 
        list<pair<string, size_t>> pokemons_;
};
```

where "size_t" is an identifier for the pokemon name.
I have this hint in my assignment for the constructor:

```
  /* constructor
   * initializes the collection to by copying the parameter
   */
PokemonCollection(const std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>>& pokemons){}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOkb0.png)

Comment: The member being a list doesn't change anything. If it was a plain `int`, how would you initialize it with a constructor parameter? Do the same thing for your list.

Comment: sir I've edited and uploaded the hint for the constructor in my assignment, Its quite confusing.

Comment: It is not clear what is confusing you - have you tried to add the constructor that you were given to your code?

Comment: I added ```  PokemonCollection(const std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>>& pokemons){
}

but I don't know how to initialize the private member list of my class through that constructor.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: the list name is added, its pokemons_

apologies

Comment: @JackSparrow *the deadline is near* -- Well, [read this concerning deadlines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Comment: Despite what the hint says, it should be `PokemonCollection(std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> pokemons) : pokemons_(std::move(pokemons)) {}` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to initializes a collection (list) by copying the parameters from a constructor?

Just like you would initialize any other data member in the **member initializer list**:

```
class PokemonCollection{
    public: 
        void print();
        PokemonCollection(const std::list<std::pair<std::string,
//---------------------------------------------------VVVVVVVVVVVVVVV--->use member initializer list
                                size_t>>& pokemons): myList(pokemons)
                                {

                                }
    private: 
        list<pair<string, size_t>> myList;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h5az15619)

Note that in your given example, you had not given any name to the list data member, so in my example I've named it `myList`. Then `myList` is initialized with the function parameter named `pokemons` using the member initializer list.

Comment: I'm sorry, thats the problem, I don't understand how to do it. I'm new to list.

Comment: @JackSparrow Ok, which exact part do you find confusing in my given example. Can you pinpiont. I would also recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). These books are also available as PDFs for free. See also this [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h5az15619).

Comment: what you did there :mylist(pokemons){ }   in constructor confuses me, also the cpprefernce on internet is so professional wording and confusing.

Comment: theres nothing in the body of constructor, how am I supposed to add all those pairs while calling from main() into my private list? or do this automatically copies everything into the private list?

Comment: @JackSparrow `:myList(pokemons}` means that you're telling the compiler to **initialize** the data member named `myList` with the *initializer/argument* `pokemons`. You should refer to THE BEST book for beginners called **C++ Primer by Lippman**. These things are very well explained in that book. Also use the latest version of the book which is think is the  5th edition. Here is a link to the book [C++ Primer by Lippman 5th edition](https://zhjwpku.com/assets/pdf/books/C++.Primer.5th.Edition_2013.pdf).

Comment: tysm sir, as I've no time for further reading, can you help me in printing the list?

Comment: *tysm sir, as I've no time for further reading* -- It is unreasonable to ask someone to drop everything their doing because you have no time.  It doesn't work that way here.  Next time, budget your time a little better.

Comment: @JackSparrow You're welcome. See Page number 265 of [this](https://zhjwpku.com/assets/pdf/books/C++.Primer.5th.Edition_2013.pdf) where you'll find a section with title *"Constructor Initializer List"*. The topic is explained in more detail there.

Comment: sure I'll read it all, I've posted an image above, can you kindly give me a hint for that? it asks for two constructors, the one you helped me with has worked. Also I'll try to do better next time thanks.

Comment: @JackSparrow Do you want to print the list? If yes, then see this [working demo that prints the list](https://godbolt.org/z/fbqK1xEea). I've added some comment in that [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fbqK1xEea) so that you can see what changes i've made.

Comment: tysm sir, I'm so thanksful. sure I'll see it.

Comment: @JackSparrow You're welcome again :) Btw the demo uses *"range based for loop"* to print the list.

Comment: tysm sirrr.....